# Provider Hosted App in VM

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio, iis

Is it possible to run a provider hosted app from a vm on the same server as Sharepoint? And if so should i do it or is there a better way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to create provider hosted apps in a VM which already has SharePoint installed. If you target the on premise SharePoint, this type of app is called High trust app. A high trust provider-hosted app can establish trust with SharePoint by using digital certificates. For more information see this: http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/02/sharepoint-2013-provider-hosted-app.html

Comment: Do i need to seperate the Sharepoint and the remote web?

Comment: @CodeCat, you can have both of them on the same machine. SharePoint will have separate IIS site and remote web will also have a separate IIS site.

Comment: Can my visual studio be on the same maschine?

Comment: @CodeCat, yes it can be. The link I provided had all of these on one VM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create and run a provider hosted on the same machine as the SharePoint installation. This kind of provider hosted app where SharePoint and app will be on premise and you will be calling server-to-server is termed as a high-trust app. There are a few steps you need to carry out in order to get this working eg. setting up trust between the app and sharepoint. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179901(v=office.15).aspx) is a guide to start with.